# will java17 work on older version of Android studio (specifically Android studio 1.5.1)

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a system of 2ig ram so I was recommended to download and install Android studio 1.5.1 with java 7...

But I already have java17 installed..
Any Reason why won't java17 work on older version of Android studio specifically Android studio 1.5.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Each version of Android Studio is designed to support a specific (maximum) version of Android.

That version of Android requires a specific version of the Java compiler to create its packages.

Java 17 (and indeed all versions from 9 and up) aren't (fully) backwards compatible with Java 8 and below.

It's not that you couldn't run the later versions of Android Studio without having an older Java SDK installed (it comes with its own built-in Java runtime for that), but you won't be able to successfully compile things.

Recommending Java 1.7 however is a big nono, that version has been out of support for years. At the very least you want Java 8.